# how do I swap Id with another value in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to swap each id with the item , here is an example

```js
const swapId = (id, item) => {
  const map = [
    {
      id: 1,
      item: 'fruit'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      item: 'veggies'
    }
  ]

  const newMap = map.filter((e) => e.id >= 1).map((d) => e.id[item])
  console.log(newMap)
}

swapId()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

here is what i want:

```
{id: 'fruit', item: 'fruit'},
{id: 'veggies', item: 'veggies'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```js
const swapID = () => {
      let  map =  [
          {id: 1, item: 'fruit'},
          {id:2, item: 'veggies'}
           ]
       
     for (let x of map) {
           x.id = x.item
       }
       
     return map
   }

   console.log(
       swapID()
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce method of javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Here is the function you need:

```js
function swapId() {
  const map = [

                 {id: 1, item: 'fruit'},
                {id:2, item: 'veggies'}]

return veggies.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator.id = currentValue.item
    return [...accumulator, {id: currentValue.item, item: currentValue.item}]
}, [])
}
```